# How to tackle spaces in commandline by c#

Tags: c#, cmd, processstartinfo

I have trouble executing a command via c#. The command consists of two paths, which I have to combine. Both paths contain spaces.

```
        String arguments = "/K \"" + dtExecPath + "\"" + @" /f " + "\"" + tmpPackagePath + "\"";
       // arguments = AddQuotesIfRequired(arguments);
        Console.WriteLine("TEST: " + arguments);

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
        startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = @arguments;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
```

When I execute the code, I get the following error: ""C:\Program" could not be found.

The generated command looks like this:

```
TEST: /K "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\DTEXEC.exe" /f "C:\Users\toki\source\repos\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\tmp\O2Data (1).dtsx"
```

What's the error?

Comment: Have you tried if that string actually works on the command line?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a C# problem. How arguments are parsed is up to the process you're starting (cmd), not the parent process.

Per the [docs for cmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd#remarks), you need exactly one set of quotation marks. What's not clear in the official docs is how to deal with nested quotation marks. [This page](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) indicates that you should double-quote the beginning and end; this seems to work for me:

```cs
String arguments = "/K \"\"" + dtExecPath + "\"" + @" /f " + "\"" + tmpPackagePath + "\"\"";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, by setting the startInfo.WorkingDirectory; Only then the process is executed without failure